# How do I take a flat model and wrap around an axis like a wheel?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am making tread for a car and I made a simple pattern for one section and then duplicated it a bunch of times using an array. What I want to do now is take the model that is flat and wrap it around an axis to turn it into a wheel. How do I do this?

Comment: You can use a mixture of the curve and array modifier to quickly achieve this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way is to just add an *Array* modifier to your tread or flat object, bump up the counts a bit and add a new *Bezier Circle* to the scene.

[image]

Then add a *Curve* modifier, select the correct axis *(it sometimes wacks out here, you can just apply transformations before you do this)* and tweak accordingly until it aligns properly and is arched around a portion of the curve.

[image]

Bump up the array count some more and voila, a tire or whatever object wrapped around a circle. (When doing this, you might have to select the curve and scale it accordingly so that the ends of the object meet. You can also tick *'Merge'* in the array modifier or use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to apply the modifiers and convert everything into one object, after this, if a gap still exists, it can be easily filled.

[image]

Comment: To anyone thinking this looks too much like a tutorial, it isn't. The worded version was too depressing to read, anyways I blame it on the size of the images, they make the post overly long.

Comment: I agree, blender is a visual tool. Pure text only answers simply would not be as helpful... +1 in hopes that this becomes the spirit of the  site

Comment: This is a good example of one way to make a tire. Is there a more "precise" way of doing this model than using a Bezier curve? I have read elsewhere that a Bezier is not a true circle.

Comment: @EthosErlanger Define "true circle", looks pretty circular to me. A [query on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=model+a+tire+blender) should get some good results. There are also other answers below.

Comment: @iKlsR Yes it looks good.   A circle is π*R Squared. My understanding of a Bezier is that it is a cubic equation that only approximates a circle.

Answer (score 10):

Let's not forget the grandfather: Warp

In edit mode, position the cursor where your axle is supposed to be, select the mesh and hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. Make sure that your line of sight is parallel to the axle because Warp takes the orientation of the 3d view into account.

This is useful if your mesh contains other parts or you are just too lazy to use modifiers and later change is not necessary.

Use numerical input and finisch the modifier with <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd> to get a full circle.

If you want a precise diameter, position the cursor on an outer vertex with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> and then use the 3d cursor panel to move it down (or move the mesh up with numerical input)

[image: Blender Warp Shift W]

Answer (score 9):

There are a variety of ways of doing this, but one of the simplest is just to use the *Array* modifier with 'Object Offset'.

Model the object you wish to wrap around and place an empty where you want the center of your wheel to be located. Place your object's center at the same location as the empty (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>>*Selection to Cursor (Offset)*). Add an *Array* modifier on your object and select 'Object Offset':

[image]

Rotate the empty very slightly, and bring the array count high enough, and the array should wrap all the way around in a circle.

[image]

If you want to do further smoothing, you can apply the *Array* modifier, then use all of the usual tricks (subdivision surface, smooth lighting, Boolean union, etc).