# How to make an arch in a model w/o Bezier Curves and w/o adding separate objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I would like to curve a line in order to make a medieval door.

I'm talking about this curve:

[image: Curve]

I can't understand and I can't find any tutorial that tells you how to make this kind of curves, also I would like to not use the Blazer curves.
I'm trying to find something easier because I would like to know how to use less time in order to make curves.

I saw that you can do it using the array modifier but it can't be used on edit mode, should I add another object? Is it a good practice to add objects to modify the main one?

This is where I'm trying to make this door.. 
Thank you and sorry for wasting your time, I'm just a beginner..

Edit: Why my question is not a duplicate of another -->

These are different questions, I'm not asking how to do it with a single object, I'm asking how to do it if I have a building, because the modifiers don't work if you are in edit mode, so I'm asking how to make a arch if I have for example a house and I want to have a arch door or arch windows. It's a different thing.. 
I would like also to know if it's a good practice adding new objects to another one, because using this way I can for example make a cylinder and remove half etc..

[image]
[image]

Edit: The solution from @moonboots worked! Thank you

Result:

[image]

[image]

**Thank you!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I create an arch?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21698/how-would-i-create-an-arch)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/make-arch-thicker-but-retain-diameter and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-do-i-take-a-flat-model-and-wrap-around-an-axis-like-a-wheel/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-use-array-to-create-circular-array-without-spiralling/23664#23664

Comment: These are different questions, I'm not asking how to do it with a single object, I'm asking how to do it if I have a building, because the modifiers don't work if you are in edit mode, so I'm asking how to make a arch if I have for example a house and I want to have a arch door or arch windows. It's a different thing..

Comment: The two options I would recommend are to create a separate object using the array technique and then joining it back on Ctrl+j or to create a Bezier curve and use the Knife Project to cut it into your building to give you the correct faces for extrusion.

Comment: So it's a correct way to create a new object everytime I want to make a curve / arch?

Or there is something easier that I can do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've kept your topology but no need for so many edge loops. Anyway, you could use the *Bridge* tool:

- First, tilt a bit the top faces of your left and right columns.
- Press <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > *Bridge*, or <kbd>W</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*.
- Play with the parameters on the bottom of the *Tools* panel.
- Fill the hole the way you want to finish the work. Here are 2 ways to do it, maybe there's a better one though.

[image]

Comment: Finally! Thank you really! This is exactly what I was waiting for and that I didn't find anywhere. Thank you!

 http://i66.tinypic.com/2v1olmp.png

Now I try to do this with my building, if it will work I will tell you thanks again!

Comment: Also, note that there isn't any need to add tons of edge loops on your entire mesh. You want to keep your mesh as simple as possible. Having additional edge loops temporary is ok, as long as you know how to manage them later on.

Comment: Sure thank you for this, I will try to remove them, by the way the solution from @moonboots worked so thank you all again!

Comment: yes, I've kept your topology but no need for so many edge loops  ;)

Comment: @moonboots can you also help me with this, I have merged all the holes, but now it has a different shade: http://i66.tinypic.com/bikln6.png

And inside the building there is something wrong: http://i63.tinypic.com/14vtte0.png and http://i68.tinypic.com/2w3tfeg.png

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: it's not clear, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5620" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5620/)

here thank you

Comment: you have faces overlaying, you need to merge some vertices like I've done here: https://zupimages.net/up/18/50/zzkv.jpg   but you should follow some modeling tutorials to avoid this kind of mistakes  ;)

Comment: Understood, thank you for your help!

Hope that this discussion would be usefull for other people, thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome, maybe put "arch" in your title to make it more clear and so that it pops up when someone makes a search, example: how to make an arch or something like that

Comment: Snappy!  This one made me chuckle.. :D

Comment: oh ok, I thought you would know this trick  ;)

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to press <kbd>O</kbd> to turn on proportional editing and pull one of the bricks up, you can modify range of the proportional editing using mouse roll.

Another idea would be to make it by hand by moving verticles.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply,

I tried with the proportional editing but it will "move" the whole building, for example if I have the top of the door near the roof, it will move the whole roof up, defacing it.. tried also with moving vertices by hand but it's like I can't get a arch, it will remain a square up and down.. 

Is it a bad thing adding a new object like a cylinder and make a arch from it? Or it's correct? Otherwise I don't really know how I can handle a curve like this