# How can I make these objects in the shape of a circle

Tags: objects

how can I make these objects in the shape of a circle[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6m5r7Uq-Khg

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21698

Answer (score 5):

Simple deform modifier seems well suited for this job.

1. Set it to Bend
2. Choose desired axis (Z in my example)
3. Enter a 360° angle (full circle)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be of help :). You can also mark the answer as accepted ✔.